# python turtle screen is not show correct

Tags: python

I'm python newbie, I used `pyenv` install python on my mac, my python version

```
➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.10.3
```

And this is my code

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("red")
screen.title("My Snake Game")

segment_1 = Turtle("square")
segment_1.color("white")

screen.exitonclick()
```

When I run this code

```
$ python main.py
```

The result is not I want

[image: result]

When I close the gui, I got this message

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/li/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    screen.bgcolor("red")
  File "/Users/li/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 1238, in bgcolor
    color = self._colorstr(args)
  File "/Users/li/.pyenv/versions/3.10.3/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 1159, in _colorstr
    raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad color string: %s" % str(color))
turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: red
```

How could I fix it, Thanks.

Comment: Your code is working perfectly fine on my computer (I am using windows)

Comment: Are you sure you're using python3? When using python2 i get the same output as you, using python3 it's fine as expected.

Comment: I had try `python3 main.py`, the result is same.

Comment: but I found I use `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 main.py` this is work, I have no idea.

Comment: I found solution, I have to upgrade `tcl-tk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the `tcl-tk` version. Original `tcl-tk` version is **8.5**.

I use brew to install `tcl-tk`

```
$ brew install tcl-tk
```

And reinstall python

```
$ pyenv uninstall 3.10.3
$ pyenv install 3.10.3
```

The `tcl-tk` version become **8.6**